# How to filter entity framework result with multiple columns using a lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, lambda

I have the following table:

[image]

And the following data:

[image]

How can i filter the result, so that i only get the latest row from each `omraade_id` (sorted descending by `timestamp`)?

Which in this case would be the rows with id: `1010` and `1005`

--

From @lazyberezovsky's answer, i have created the following expression:

```
dbConnection = new ElecEntities();

            var query = from data in dbConnection.Valgdata
            orderby data.timestamp descending
            group data by data.omraade_id into g
            select g.FirstOrDefault();

            return query.ToList();
```

It returns two rows with the ID 3 and 4, which are the first two rows in the database, and also the ones with the lowest timestamp. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with EF, so I'm unsure if only SQL-esque linq works here. A plain C#-ish:

```
var query = dbConnection.Valgdata.GroupBy(u => u.omraade_id)
      .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => x.Max(p => p.timestamp) == y.timestamp));
```

Comment: @Kenci why is it FirstOrDefault? `First` works in all cases! Because you will always have a maximum timestamp no matter what.

Comment: The timestamp column is nullable, and it throws an error when i execute the query with First() - but i should probably change this :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = dbConnection.Valgdata
                        .GroupBy(x => x.omraade_id)
                        .Select(g => g
                             .OrderByDescending(x => x.timestamp)
                             .FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. This returns all 11 rows (returns row=3 9 times and row=4 2 times) ?

Comment: Thanks again. I appreciate the effort. This returns a Grouping object with two keys. The first key contains all the rows from the first omraade_id, and the second key contains all the rows from the second omraade_id (not sorted).

Comment: @Kenci I just tried and it worked fine for me. Are you sure you have the all parenthesis in the right place?

Comment: I have copy-pasted your answer. I have uploaded an image of what i get here: http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/6407/dbgroupquery.png

Comment: @Kenci you're right, I'm sorry. Apparently, I made a mistake while trying to convert what I have to the Linq syntax. See my update.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez your edit gives wrong results. Try yourself with some sample data

Comment: @nawfal How is it wrong? I've already tried it with sample data, but realized I made a  mistake while trying to convert it to linq syntax. The latest version should work fine.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez It works sorry I made a small mistake when copy pasting your query to my IDE:)

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from v in dbConnection.Valgdata
            orderby v.timestamp descending
            group v by v.omraade_id into g
            select g.First();
```

This will return only record with max timestamp for each omraade_id.

*UPDATE* query above works fine to me (at least for MS SQL Linq provider). Also you don't need to do `FirstOrDefault` - if omraade_id is grouped, then it definitely has at least one row.

```
var query = from v in dbConnection.Valgdata
            group v by v.omraade_id into g
            select g.OrderByDesc(x => x.timestamp).First();
```

Comment: It returns the same if i write descending or ascending

Comment: @Kenci see updated answer. Maybe its linq provider specific issue. Try to order records after grouping. That definitely should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have put filter on every item. It should be applied on complete query result, not on every item.

Following is updated query.

```
 var query = (from data in dbConnection.Valgdata
        orderby data.timestamp descending
        group data by data.omraade_id into g
        select g).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried your suggestion, it returns 9 results (all the rows with id = 6)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution so far:

```
var data = dbConnection.Valgdata.Where(x => x.godkendt == false).ToList();
var dataGrouped = data.GroupBy(x => x.omraade_id).ToList();

List<Valgdata> list = new List<Valgdata>();

 foreach (var grpdata in dataGrouped)
            {
                var dataGroup = grpdata.OrderByDescending(x => x.timestamp).ToList();
                list.Add(dataGroup.FirstOrDefault());
            }
return list;
```

I dont know if it is the most effective, but it works.